# Can I intercept Spring @Autowired process to do validation checks?

Tags: java, spring, scope, autowired

Sometimes we make mistakes in our code and `@Autowired` a prototype-scoped bean into a singleton-scoped bean. This is of course wrong because then the singleton is probably going to use that dependency as if it was also a singleton.

Is there any way of intercepting the autowiring/DI process to detect this and raise an error ? This would be for detection at development time.

Comment: Interesting, indeed. But why would you consider such scenario as invalid and thus raise an error ?

Comment: You can use a prototype scoped bean in a singleton scoped bean just fine. You need to use Spring's scoped proxies support.

Comment: @kocko - because of concurrency issues when two threads use the singleton and then interacts with a prototype bean, which has internal state.

Comment: @artbristol - this would solve it but still relies on developers doing this. I would then still need to have a runtime check for the correct scoping setting.

Comment: If STS doesn't have this, I very much doubt it's possible at development time.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to achieve this is through your unit tests. For example:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MyAppConfig.class, loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class MyServiceTest {

    @Autowired(required = true)
    MyService myService;

    @Test 
    public void shouldAutowire() {}

}
```

The @ContextConfiguration can be used with Java config as above, or it can refer to XML config files. By doing this, Spring will be used to inject all of your dependencies whenever you run your tests. By including "required = true" on your @Autowired beans, you are ensuring that Spring will throw an exception during that phase, and your test will fail. The example above may not look fancy, but it will ensure that any configuration errors are caught. Of course, you can go further and have your tests make use of the injected beans. I find that rather handy for database access integration tests.

This is not intercepting the autowiring process itself, but you can of course test that your beans are behaving correctly.

You will need to import the spring-test dependency. i.e. For Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Not sure if this answers my question. The problem is not that the bean is missing, but that one bean is autowiring what I would consider to be a invalid bean, due to scoping.

Comment: Given that using the Spring JUnit support causes Spring to autowire all of your beans, you can just look at that bean to see whether it's the one you expect it to be. You can also get a reference to the Spring context if you wish to examine it.